# POST controller for all routes in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

I have callback button in header of my webpage, so user can send me message from every page.

How to make route for this? Something like that:

```
Route::post('{*}', 'PostController@callback');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing some try and check I found that the most simple route allows sending callback request from every page!!!

```
Route::get('/', ['as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'HomeController@index']);
Route::post('/', ['as' => 'callback', 'uses' => 'PostController@callback']);
```

But I don't know why. If someone know why please tell me, because I really want to know the background.
I was also trying to do it using middleware as I was advised. It was also working solution. Messages were sending from every page, but with message I got 403 error code in console every time. And of course I was trying to get rid of that.
With this simple solution it works without any errors in console.

Answer (score 0):

Use middleware so you can check every request for certain post-data.
I would do it like this: create a file called MessageMiddleware.php in the directory App\Http\Middleware\

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class MessageMiddleware {
    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        if(isset($_POST['internal_message'])) {
            // Do something so the message reaches you (db, email, whatever)
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
?>
```

This is just a very basic version but should give you an idea. 
You will not have to register any routes for this and the middleware will work for all urls the middleware is registered for.

If you want a middleware to be run during every HTTP request to your application, simply list the middleware class App\Http\Middlware\MessageMiddleware in the $middleware property of your app/Http/Kernel.php class.

The official Laravel documentation for Middlware is very extensive and does certainly not only cover authentication middleware.

Comment: never used middleware before. Do you know what to read to understand it better, because I found only documentation about using middleware for auth requests.

Comment: doing this 
`
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use App\Models\Access\User\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification;




class CalculationDone
{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if(isset($_POST)) {
            Notification::send(User::findOrFail(1), new CalculationDone($request));
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
`


gives me error
 `FatalErrorException in ChannelManager.php line 62: Call to undefined method App\Http\Middleware\CalculationDone::via()`

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you do it via `ajax`.

Comment: Actually I am on this way already, but still not working. Can you help? Here is the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39190857/submit-form-from-all-website-pages-using-angular) to another question regarding ajax.