# submit form from all website pages in Laravel 5.1 using Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel-5.1

I have callback button in header of my webpage, so user can send me message from every page.

Instead having special `Route::post` in routes.php I decided to create PostMiddleware.
Doing this I expect that on every page of my web-site all POST requests will be analized and if they contain field `formname` then JSON data is sending in mail message to me.

But I have few issues:
1) Callback form working fine from ALMOST every page of my web-site, but anyway every time I can see 405 error code in console. As far as I understand this error, because I don't have special route for POST request. But I don't know how to remove this error. Just add `Route::post` is not what I want to do, since I hope that Middleware should be better.

2) Callback form is not working from web-page, where I have another form `<form ng-app="SaunaDoorCalc" ng-controller="SaunaDoorCalcController" class="calculator" name="calculator">`. On this webpage only SaunaDoorCalc form is working. And when I click on `ng-click="submit(callback.$valid)"` nothing happens in console.

### my code is below

button

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-large" href="#callback" title="Обратный звонок" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#callback">
```

then here is html of my callback form

```
<div class="modal fade" id="callback" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="callback" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <form ng-app="callback" name="callback" ng-controller="callbackController" role="form" class="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {{ csrf_field() }}


    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="CallbackModalLabel"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o text-primary"></i>  Отправить письмо / Попросить перезвонить</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">


        <div class="text-primary">* обязательное поле</div>


        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="input">
            <input id="name" name="name" ng-model="name" type="text" required>
            <label for="name">Ваше имя *</label>
          </div>
          <div class="input">
            <input id="phone" name="tel" ng-model="tel" type="text"  required>
            <label for="phone">Номер телефона *</label>
          </div>
          <div class="input">
            <input id="time" name="time" ng-model="time" type="text">
            <label for="time">Желательное время звонка</label>
          </div>

          <div class="input">
            <input id="email" name="email" ng-model="email" type="email">
            <label for="email">Адрес электронной почты</label>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="input">
            <textarea id="msg" name="msg" ng-model="msg"></textarea>
            <label for="message">Сообщение *</label>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>

            <div class="input-group margin-bottom-20">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
                    <i class="fa fa-paperclip"> </i>
                        Прикрепить файл 
                    <input type="file" name="file" id='file' multiple="">
                    </span>
                </span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly="">
        </div>


      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="submit(callback.$valid)">Отправить</button>
      </div>

     </div>
    </form>


  </div>
</div>
```

here is the angular module

```
angular
  .module('callback', [])
  .controller('callbackController', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.outerScope = {};
    $scope.formData = {};

    $scope.url = '/';



    $scope.submit = function(isValid) {
      if (isValid) {
          $http.post($scope.url, 
            {
              "formname": "callback", // this field to distinguish different ajax forms, which have different mail template
              "name": $scope.name, 
              "tel": $scope.tel, 
              "time": $scope.time, 
              "email": $scope.email, 
              "msg": $scope.msg, 
            }).
                        success(function(data, status) {
                            console.log(data);
                            $scope.status = status;
                            $scope.data = data;
                            $scope.result = data; 
                        });
              $scope.name = null;
              $scope.tel = null;
              $scope.email = null;
              $scope.msg = null;
              $scope.callback.$setPristine();
            }else{
              $('.errors').modal('show');; 
            }

        }


  });
```

app\Http\Middleware\PostMiddleware.php

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use URL;
use Event;
use App\Events\SendMail;

class PostMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->formname) {
            $result = $request->all();
            Event::fire(new SendMail($result));
            }
        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

\app\Events\SendMail.php

```
namespace App\Events;

use App\Events\Event;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class SendMail extends Event
{
    use SerializesModels;


    public $result;

    public function __construct($result)
    {
        $this->result = $result;
    }


    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

\app\Listeners\SendMailFired.php

```
namespace App\Listeners;
use Mail;
use App\Events\SendMail;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class SendMailFired
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }


    public function handle(SendMail $event)
    {
        $mailarray = $event->result;

            switch ($mailarray['formname']) {

                case "callback":
                    Mail::send('emails.callback', $mailarray, function($message) use ($mailarray) {
                        $message->from($mailarray['email'], $mailarray['name'] );
                        $message->to('info@site.ru', 'noreply');
                        $message->setCc($mailarray['email'], $mailarray['name']);
                        $message->replyTo($mailarray['email'], $mailarray['name'] );
                        $message->subject('Обратный звонок с сайта');
                    });
                    break;

                case "saunadoor":
                    Mail::send('emails.sauna-calculator', $mailarray, function($message) use ($mailarray) {
                        $message->from($mailarray['email'], $mailarray['name'] );
                        $message->to('info@site.ru', 'noreply');
                        $message->setCc($mailarray['email'], $mailarray['name']);
                        $message->replyTo($mailarray['email'], $mailarray['name'] );
                        $message->subject('Заказ двери для сауны');
                    });
                    break;
            }

    }
}
```

\app\Http\Kernel.php

```
namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{

    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\PostMiddleware::class,
    ];

    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    ];
}
```

here is route error

```
 1/1 MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:

    in RouteCollection.php line 218
    at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('GET', 'HEAD')) in RouteCollection.php line 205
    at RouteCollection->getRouteForMethods(object(Request), array('GET', 'HEAD')) in RouteCollection.php line 158
    at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 750
    at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 659
    at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 635
    at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 236
    at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in PostMiddleware.php line 26
    at PostMiddleware->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
    at call_user_func_array(array(object(PostMiddleware), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 50
    at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
    at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
    at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
    at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 62
    at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
    at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
    at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
    at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
    at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
    at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
    at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
    at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
    at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 122
    at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 87
    at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

Comment: I found answer to question 2. That was because I did separate angular module for each form.  I didn't know that only one ng-app could be loaded automatically on one page. So to make 2 forms working in one page I changed my angular script like this `angular.module('myapp', [])
  .controller('callbackController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {    
  }])
  .controller('calculatorController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) }
  }])`

Comment: not just need to understand what's wrong with routes!